# Генерация IP адресов

Tags: php, циклы

Как можно реализовать цикл генерации IP адресов по такому алгоритму:

Как мы знаем, IP адрес состоит из маски

```
*.*.*.*
```

Допустим, у нас IP 94.122.67.83

Нужно создать такие IP адреса в которых:

Сумма цифр 1 и 2 части будут равны, тоесть: 9+4+1+2+2 = 6+7+8+3

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, Вы сожалели, что код на Си просто перебор вариантов, а не Ваша задача. Я сделал вывод "счастливых" IP. Код в UPDATE моего ответа. Вместе с выводом 3084214728 байт в /dev/null 27 sec на DualCore 2.7 GHz (всего 215397594 IP).

Comment: @avp Я не могу понять, или я идиот, или php, cи и питон лагают. Си не компилит код, php.exe открывает чёрное окно и всё, python запускать отказывается. :(

Comment: Я пользуюсь в Windows (и и XP 32-bit и в 7 64-bit) MinGW gcc. 

Только что я попробовал еще раз. В Emacs открыл файл **ips.c** скопировал (Copy/Paste) в него текст из моего ответа (тот что после **UPDATE-2**) и сохранил.

В окошке консоли (**cmd**) выполнил команды:

    chcp 1251
    gcc -O3 -o ips ips.c
    ips > nul

Нужный шрифт в консоли у меня уже стоит. Как сделать см. мой комментарий внизу. Все отработало за 24730 msec.

Опишите **подробно** что делаете, что видите.

Comment: Всё, результата я уже достиг. PHP CLI у меня до сих пор не запускается. (просто чёрное окно консоли - ничего больше). Python выдавал ошибку на 1 строчке. А дальше, что только не делал. Помог Dev-C++

Comment: Конечно поздно, но!:

Зачем вам это надо **хранить**? Как вы это хотите использовать?

Comment: To @timka_s, в самом низу есть комментарий автора, чего он хочет.

Comment: Вот чушь.... А базу проксей не проще сразу протестить?)

Comment: :(
Я хотел разнообразия. Главное что всем вопрос понравился, и у всех разный подход к решению задачи. Мне было приятно прочитать все ваши ответы и комментарии.

Comment: Вы идёте в неверном направлении:

Если правило такое простое, то надо не искать **Пересечение множеств 1к1**, а **Просеивать имеющееся**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ips = array();
for ($n1 = 0; $n1 < 256; $n1++)
  for ($n2 = 0; $n2 < 256; $n2++)
    for ($n3 = 0; $n3 < 256; $n3++)
      for ($n4 = 0; $n4 < 256; $n4++) {
        $sn1 = $sn2 = 0;
        $strn12 = $n1.$n2;
        $strn34 = $n3.$n4;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($strn12); $i++)
          $sn1 += (int) $strn12{$i};
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($strn34); $i++)
          $sn2 += (int) $strn34{$i};
        if ($sn1 == $sn2)
          $ips []= "$n1.$n2.$n3.$n4";
      }
print_r($ips);
```

Скрипт выдаст все возможные IP (v4), описанные в вопросе. И таки да, мсье знает толк в извращениях)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in gen.php on line 11

Comment: Пардон, `; $i++` дописал. Вы аккуратнее с запуском, я вообще не представляю, сколько он работать будет. Попробовали бы сперва на малых числах (не 256, а 11, например).

Comment: Если что, у меня ещё вся ночь впереди. Сделаю чтобы все IP записались в файл, max_execution_time поставлю 9999 на виртуалке и спать

Comment: Отдал вам всю свою репутацию. Теперь у вас 7к :)

Comment: Да, спасибо, на самом деле вряд ли ответ того заслужил) `max_execution_time` лучше ставить 0. 9999 - это меньше 3 часов)

Comment: @Sh4dow, при всем уважении, могли бы и более изящней написать :)

Comment: @shurik об этом мой предыдущий камент) Решение топориком выбито, знаю. На самом деле, просто задача странная - практически уверен, что такой список никому не нужен. Сразу пришла мысль, что ТС хочет сделать что-то вроде ["счастлигового ip"](http://2ip.ru/happy-ip/), но тут просто в реалтайме более логично проверять, чем искать в базе. Либо хочет получить инвайт через прокси, но и тогда проще по списку доступных проверять)

Comment: Вы правильно подумали :)
Хочу сгенерировать базу из "счастливых" проксей.
Вообще я начинающий программист, и каждый ваш ответ, я рассматриваю :)

Comment: Ну вот в вашем случае логгично просто перед заносом прокси в базу делать примерно так:

    // $proxy - объект с проксей(ip, порт, дата и пр.)
    $num = explode('.', $proxy->ip);
    $left = $right = 0;
    foreach (array($num[0], $num[1]) as $n)
      $left += floor($n * 0.01) + floor(($n % 100)*0.1) + ($n % 10);
    foreach (array($num[2], $num[3]) as $n)
      $right += floor($n * 0.01) + floor(($n % 100)*0.1) + ($n % 10);
    if ($left == $right)
      $proxy->is_happy = true;

А хранить ради этой цели базу в 3+ГБ мне кажется странным) Тем более, не факт, что запрос к ней пройдет быстрее

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант с некоторой оптимизацией, могу предложить такое ( JavaScript ):

```
console.time( 'test' );

function num2sum( val ){
  return (
      ~~( val / 100 )
    + ~~( val % 100 / 10 )
    + ~~( val % 10 )
  );
}

sum = [];
for ( i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) sum.push( num2sum( i ) );

pair = [];
for ( n1 = 0; n1 < 256; n1++ ){
  for ( n2 = 0; n2 < 256; n2++ ){
    sum2 = sum[ n1 ] + sum[ n2 ];

    ( pair[ sum2 ] || ( pair[ sum2 ] = [] ) ).push( '.' + n1 + '.' + n2 );
  }
}

res = [];
for ( n1 = 0; n1 < 256; n1++ ){
  console.log(n1);
  for ( n2 = 0; n2 < 256; n2++ ){
    sum2 = sum[ n1 ] + sum[ n2 ];

    sum34 = pair[ sum2 ];
    for ( n34 = 0; n34 < sum34.length; n34++ ){
      res.push( n1 + '.' + n2 + sum34[ n34 ] );
    }
  }
}

console.timeEnd( 'test' );
```

Генерация всех IP из `[0-25].*.*.*` заняла `99058ms` - и примерно 600 МБ оперативки

Для всех IP из условия ( а их - 215397594 ) нужно 3ГБ минимум.

Answer (score 5):

1. Т.к. по условию задачи, левая и правая части IP адреса равны, то нету смысла перебирать все варианты, достаточно перебрать только левую (или правую) часть.
2. Так же, т.к. валидными являются все варианты левой части, то разумно сразу сгенерировать все возможные варианты левой части с заранее рассчитанной суммой.

Запускать через php_cli.

```
function sum($string) {
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $result += (int)$string[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}

$ipSet = array();

for ($part1 = 1; $part1 < 255; $part1++) {
    $sum1 = sum((string)$part1);

    for ($part2 = 1; $part2 < 255; $part2++) {
        $numberSum = $sum1 + sum((string)$part2);
        if (isset($ipSet[$numberSum])) {
            $ipSet[$numberSum][] = "$part1.$part2";
        } else {
            $ipSet[$numberSum] = array("$part1.$part2");
        }
    }
}

foreach ($ipSet as $ipParts) {
    foreach ($ipParts as $partLeft) {
        foreach ($ipParts as $partRight) {
            fwrite(STDOUT, "$partLeft.$partRight\n");
        }
    }
}
```

И тоже самое на питоне:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

ip_set = defaultdict(lambda : [])

for part1 in range(1, 255):
    sum1 = sum(map(int, str(part1)))

    for part2 in range(1, 255):
        number_sum = sum1 + sum(map(int, str(part2)))
        ip_set[number_sum].append('%d.%d' % (part1, part2))

for ip_parts in ip_set.values():
    for part_left in ip_parts:
        for part_right in ip_parts:
            # заменил print на прямой вывод в stdout
            sys.stdout.write( '%s.%s\n' % (part_left, part_right) )
```

UPD. Ради спортивного интереса запустил все листинги у себя. Получились следующие результаты:

PHP, интерпретатор PHP 5.3.8

```
$ time php ips.php >/dev/null

real    7m41.531s
user    6m52.086s
sys     0m47.807s
```

Python, интерпретатор python 3.2

```
$ time python3.2 ips.py > /dev/null

real    2m41.555s
user    2m40.742s
sys     0m0.212s
```

Python, интерпретатор pypy 1.7 с включенной JIT-компиляцией

```
$ time pypy ips.py > /dev/null

real    0m47.937s
user    0m47.415s
sys     0m0.344s
```

C, листинг от [[[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) скомпилирован gcc 4.6.2 (пришлось выпилить от туда mtime, из-за отсутствия таковой функции)

```
$ gcc -O3 -march=native -mtune=native ipc2.c -o ipc2
$ time ./ipc2 > /dev/null
Поиск количества "Счастливых" IP (nested loops)
Всего 215397594 "Счастливых" IP вывод 3084214728 байт

real    0m22.702s
user    0m22.597s
sys     0m0.020s
```

C, перебор всех вариантов от [[[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)

```
$ gcc -O2 ips.c -o ips
$ time ./ips > /dev/null
End 295  str=255.255.255.255

real    4m54.712s
user    4m51.914s
sys      0m1.676s
```

Comment: Просто ради интереса: на Си Linux под VirtualBox на 32-bit Windows-XP Dual-Core 2.7 GHz с записью всех результатов в /dev/null 1m 3.90s

Размер программы - 49 строк. **К вопросу об эффективности сред программирования**

Comment: Разумеется, я бы удивился, если было бы иначе :) Кроме того, я привел более "честные" результаты с выводом в файл. С выводом в /dev/null было бы раза в два быстрее.

Кстати, привели бы тогда уж исходник на C

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Предполагаю, что если бы у вас был перебор только IP удовлетворяющих условию, то время выполнения было бы меньше. Но даже такие результаты, по моему, весьма показательны :) Особенно если учесть количество кода :)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, если хотите дополнить свою статистику, то я сделал оптимизированную программку на Си (она в UPDATE-2 моего ответа), которая **выводит** IP, соответствующие условию, так сказать, "счастливые".

Время работы у меня 27 сек. при выводе в /dev/null ~3Gbytes. Компилировал **gcc -O3**

Comment: @avp, обновил. С флагом -O2 никакой разницы у себя не заметил.

Так же добавил результат своего кода на PHP, чуть больше 7 минут проработал.

Правда есть небольшое отличие, у себя я исключил невалидные IP вроде 0.1.0.1 и 255.255.255.255.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, здорово, отличная таблица. При записи "счастливых" в файл, думаю особой разницы между C и pypy не будет. 

У меня в файл записалось почти за 2 мин.

Answer (score 5):

Генерация и вывод всех адресов на Си

Только что обнаружил ошибку в ней, результат, приведенный внизу (с учетом вывода) не корректен.
**puts(str); надо перенести во внутренний цикл**
В этом случае (вывод в /dev/null т.к. на диске у меня места под 64Гбайт файл нет)
время работы 4m 43.46s

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <time.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  int  i,n1,n2,n3,n4;
  char str[100], *p, *q;
  char *nn[256];

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    sprintf (str,"%d",i);
    nn[i] = strdup(str);
  }

  time_t start = time(NULL);
  for (n1 = 0; n1 < 256; n1++)
    for (n2 = 0; n2 < 256; n2++) {
      for (n3 = 0; n3 < 256; n3++) {
    for (n4 = 0; n4 < 256; n4++) {

      p = str;
      q = nn[n1];
      while (*q)
        *p++ = *q++;
      *p++ = '.';
      q = nn[n2];
      while (*q)
        *p++ = *q++;
      *p++ = '.';
      q = nn[n3];
      while (*q)
        *p++ = *q++;
      *p++ = '.';
      q = nn[n4];
      while (*q)
        *p++ = *q++;
      *p++ = 0;

    }
    puts(str);
      }
    }

  fprintf (stderr,"End %ld  str=%s\n",time(NULL)-start,str);
  exit(0);
}
```

При копи-паст слегка отступы сползли.

Запустил с записью в файл на диск 1m 13.08s размер файла 246808576 байт.

***комментарий***
Да питон с 19 минутами это здорово. Язык мне (заочно) симпатичен. Не думал, что такой шустрый интерпретатор.

---

**UPDATE**

Да. Комментарии закончились. Ради интереса сделал еще один оптимизированный вариант и **записал все IP на диск**

```
avp@avp-ubu1:/media/sf_sharedir$ head iplist 
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.2
0.0.0.3
0.0.0.4
0.0.0.5
0.0.0.6
0.0.0.7
0.0.0.8
0.0.0.9
avp@avp-ubu1:/media/sf_sharedir$ tail iplist 
255.255.255.247
255.255.255.248
255.255.255.249
255.255.255.250
255.255.255.251
255.255.255.252
255.255.255.253
255.255.255.254
255.255.255.255
avp@avp-ubu1:/media/sf_sharedir$ ll /media/sf_sharedir/iplist 
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 68719476736 2012-01-13 00:05 /media/sf_sharedir/iplist*
avp@avp-ubu1:/media/sf_sharedir$
```

Машина I5-2500 3.3 GHz 4GB Windows-7 64-bit, VirtualBox Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit 4cpu 1GB

Время генерации с записью в /dev/null 29.043 sec, с записью в файл 719769 msec (12 минут).

Оптимизированный код:

```
/*
  Перебор разных IP

 */

#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <time.h>

long long mtime(void);

// 1. Тривиальный перебор 2^32, генерация строковой формы
main (int ac, char *av)
{
  long long start = mtime();
  int  l, n1, n2, n3, n4, k1, k2, k3;
  char *outbuf = malloc((l = 256*256*16)+1);
  outbuf[l] = 0;
  char str[20],  *digs[256], *p, *q;

  fprintf (stderr,"Тривиальный перебор 4 млрд. IP\n");
  for (n1 = 0; n1 < 256; n1++) {
    sprintf (str,"%d",n1);
    digs[n1] = strdup(str);
  }

  for (n1 = 0; n1 < 256; n1++) {
    for (k1 = 0, q = digs[n1]; *q; k1++)
      str[k1] = *q++;
    str[k1++] = '.';
    for (n2 = 0; n2 < 256; n2++) {
      for (k2 = k1, q = digs[n2]; *q; k2++)
    str[k2] = *q++;
      str[k2++] = '.';
      p = outbuf;
      for (n3 = 0; n3 < 256; n3++) {
    for (k3 = k2, q = digs[n3]; *q; k3++)
      str[k3] = *q++;
    str[k3++] = '.'; // здесь k3 длина str
    for (n4 = 0; n4 < 256; n4++) {
      memcpy(p,str,k3);
      p+=k3;
      for (q = digs[n4]; *q;)
        *p++ = *q++;
      *p++ = '\n';
    }
      }
      write (1,outbuf,p-outbuf);
      // fprintf (stderr,"%sXXX\n",str);
    }
  }

  fprintf (stderr,"End %lld msec\n",mtime()-start);
  exit (0);
}
```

Функция mtime() возвращает текущее время в миллисекундах, для экономии места опускаю ее код.

М.б. будет время и желание сделаю параллельный вариант (IMHO время с записью на диск все равно останется порядка 12  мин.), попробую загрузить все 4 cpu.

---

**UPDATE-2**

Программа выводит все "счастливые" IP. Вместе с выводом 3084214728 байт в /dev/null 27 sec на DualCore 2.7 GHz (всего 215397594 IP).

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <time.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#define mtime clock
#else
long long mtime(void);
#endif

#define OUTPUT 1
main ()
{
  long long start = mtime(), sumo = 0;
  int b, b1, b2, b3, b4, s1, s2, ss1, ss2, k = 0;
#if OUTPUT
  char *outbuf = malloc(256*256*16+1);
  char str[20],  *digs[256], *p, *q;

  for (b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
    sprintf (str,"%d",b);
    digs[b] = strdup(str);
  }
#endif

  fprintf (stderr,"Поиск количества \"Счастливых\" IP (nested loops)\n");

  for (b1 = 0; b1 < 256; b1++) {
    b = b1;
    s1 = b%10; b = b/10;
    s1 += b%10;
    s1 += b/10;
    // fprintf (stderr,"%d.x.x.x\n",b1);
    for (b2 = 0; b2 < 256; b2++) {
      b = b2;
      ss1 = s1 + b%10; b = b/10;
      ss1 += b%10;
      ss1 += b/10;
#if OUTPUT
      p = outbuf;
#endif
      for (b3 = 0; b3 < 256; b3++) {
    b = b3;
    s2 = b%10; b = b/10;
    s2 += b%10;
    s2 += b/10;
    for (b4 = 0; b4 < 256; b4++) {
      b = b4;
      ss2 = s2 + b%10; b = b/10;
      ss2 += b%10;
      ss2 += b/10;
      if (ss1 == ss2) {
        k++;
#if OUTPUT
        for (q = digs[b1]; *q;)
          *p++ = *q++;
        *p++ = '.';
        for (q = digs[b2]; *q;)
          *p++ = *q++;
        *p++ = '.';
        for (q = digs[b3]; *q;)
          *p++ = *q++;
        *p++ = '.';
        for (q = digs[b4]; *q;)
          *p++ = *q++;
        *p++ = '\n';
#endif      
      }
    }
      }
#if OUTPUT
      write (1,outbuf,p-outbuf);
      sumo += (p-outbuf);
#endif
    }
  }

  fprintf (stderr,"Всего %d \"Счастливых\" IP (%lld msec) вывод %lld байт\n",
       k,mtime()-start,sumo);
}
```

Comment: У вас идет полный перебор, а не только IP удовлетворяющие условию, т.ч. сравнение не корректное. Но тем не менее, добавил результаты выполнения к своему ответу.

Comment: Да, просто полный перебор и генерация в строковом виде 4 млрд. раз. Просто интересно стало время работы, вот и набросал за несколько минут.

Кстати, если интересно, заменил содержимое внутреннего цикла (все эти while()...) на один **sprintf()**, думаю 90% написало бы так, и **время возросло до 35m 2.86s !**

Ваша программа на питоне это ведь не полный перебор всех IP, а решение вопроса с суммами ?

Comment: > Ваша программа на питоне это ведь не полный перебор всех IP, а решение вопроса с суммами ?

Да, именно так. Там перебор всего 210 млн. IP

Comment: Хм. Прошу прощенья, только сейчас заметил вашу ремарку про `puts(str)`. После переноса его во внутренний цикл программа уже больше получаса работает и это без замены while'ов на sprintf.

Похоже у вас где-то ошибка в алгоритме.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу активность. Я рад.
Кстати, компьютер простоял около 2ух часов, но так и не вывел результаты. Сегодня оставлю на ночь, посмотрим что будет (ночью сегодня так и не смог поставить)

Comment: Только что увидел Ваше сообщение, запустил

    /usr/bin/time ./a.out >/dev/null

жду ... уже 102.255.255.255 ... 192.255.255.255 ... 232.255.255.255 ...

    252.255.255.255
    253.255.255.255
    254.255.255.255
    255.255.255.255
    End 315  str=255.255.255.255
    307.87user 2.14system 5:15.65elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata     0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+150minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    avp@vm1-lin32-ub9:~/src$ 

Почему-то дольше, чем ранее.

Comment: To @Дмитрий Алексеевич. А **stdout** Вы куда переправили ? Если в файл, то о времени толком сказать на могу, посмотрите, он растет ? Конечный размер д.б. около 64Гбайт (реально много). 

Эта программка вообще-то просто посмотреть сколько вычисления 4 млрд. IP продлятся (про запись на диск я и не думал).

***если понадобятся еще комментарии, то они будут в добавлениях к ответу. Лимит-с***

Comment: Что уж бы добить вопрос об эффективности сред программирования. Полный перебор всех IP на питоне:

    import sys, itertools

    for ip in itertools.product(*(xrange(256),) * 4):
        sys.stdout.write( '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' % ip )

Выполняется за:

    real    19m59.251s
    user    19m43.120s
    sys     0m0.051s

Т.е. примерно в 4 раза медленнее вашего кода.

UPD. Да, интерпретатор здесь pypy. Обычный CPython, думаю, раз в 5 медленнее будет.

Comment: To @avp. Ошибся строчкой. Пользовался кодом, который дал Sh4dow

Comment: Ваш код хорош, но жалко что не по задаче

Comment: Почему код на Си не хочет компилится? в Visual Studio 2008 пишет кучу ошибок. Да-да, я не разбираюсь во всех других языках программирования. Исключением служит только дельфи

Comment: To @Дмитрий Алексеевич, в UPDATE-2 я для экономии места не включил \#include ..., которые есть в  ранее приведенном коде.

Сейчас я отредактировал ответ, у меня в Windows 7 все работает. Компилировал: **gcc -O3 -o ips ips.c**

Запуск: **ips > nul** или в файл.

Для отображения русских букв в окошке консоли перед запуском выполните команду **chcp 1251** а затем в свойствах окна консоли установите шрифт Consolas или Lucida Console. (свойства доступны по правой кнопке мыши в верхней рамке окна)

Comment: спасиибо))

Comment: Как бы теперь разбить эту базу, на несколько файлов? :)
Внёс пару правок в базу, а именно, исключил некоторые IP, начал отсчёт от 20.*.*.* ибо все IP что меньше 20, вроде либо локальны, либо ещё что-нибудь.

Comment: кстати да, время выполнения, меньше одной минуты

Comment: Вы задачку в целом (в системе с другими) опишите, а главное как сщбираетесь эти 250 млн. IP использовать. Тогда подумаем. (лучше отдельный вопрос откройте,  назовите что б понятно было, что продолжение этого).

Comment: Вообщем, у нас теперь есть база "счастливых IP". Теперь мне нужно собрать прокси, и найти совпадения в нашей базе. После этого так называемые "счастливые прокси", юзать на сайте 2ip.ru и регестрировать аккаунты. Ну лично я хотел понять генерацию, циклы и прочее, а счастливые IP, мне под руку попались

Comment: Вы же (как я понял) изучаете программирование. Вот и напишите двоичный поиск в этом файле.

По поводу нового вопроса. На ХэшКод есть лимит комментариев. Думаю в этом вопросе мы скоро его исчерпаем.

Comment: 2@avp, сможете написать код для просеивания базы проксей на наличие Счастливого IP?

Comment: И не подумаю, мне просто стало интересно насколько Си быстрее, даже если не оптимизировать алгоритм, а действовать на уровне **хорошего** компилятора. 

Собственно, если бы целью было найти **количество** или ограниченную выборку, то можно было бы поиграть с потоками, но при такой постановке задачи IO все равно все время съест, а нормальной дисковой системы сейчас под рукой нет.